# C# Find and remove all occurrences of a Word style

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, word-interop

In a Word document, I would like to find all occurrences of a style and remove them, meaning removing all the text to which the style is applied. This is a character style, so it may be applied to a single word or all words in a paragraph.

This is what I have so far:

```
public void removeStyle(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document, string styleName)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = document.Range();

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Style style = null;

    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Style currentStyle in document.Styles)
    {
        if (currentStyle.NameLocal == "Only CZ")
            style = currentStyle;
    }

    rng.Find.ClearFormatting();
    rng.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting();

    rng.Find.set_Style(style);
    rng.Find.Forward = true;
    rng.Find.Wrap = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindStop;

    //change this property to true as we want to replace format
    rng.Find.Format = true;

    rng.Find.Execute(Replace: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);
}
```

EDIT: The method above works only when the style is applied to entire paragraphs, but not when applied to individual words.

Comment: and in what way is what you have not working? Have you done some testing in the Word UI to determine the correct settings?

Comment: It seems the style object is assigned correctly, however, the Find.Execute method does not result in any modifications of the document (which is loaded correctly).

Comment: You might need to define the text for the find and replace options, typically "" if you are only searching on style information.

Comment: Tried that as well - even with Find.Text and Find.Replacement.Text specified as "", nothing is found.

Comment: The method above works only when the style is applied to entire paragraphs, but not when applied to individual words.

Comment: Are you certain this is a *character* style and not a linked style (a style that can be applied at the character and at the paragraph level). When I do a quick test in the Word UI searching a character style finds all instances, whether applied to entire paragraphs, or not. And running a replace, replacing with nothing at all, removes all these instaces.

Comment: A-ha! You're right, Cindy, I was careless enough to create a linked style instead of character. I have created a character style instead and everything seems to be working now. Cindy, Freeflow, many thanks for the help!

Comment: @Ondrej Could you please post your solution and mark that as an `Answer` so readers of your post would know that your post actually have a valid answer. I myself was about to ignore your post thinking you did not get it resolved.